# How to use Pandas to find strings in a list and export T/F Flag Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm kinda new to Python and programming in general, so here is my best effort.

Goal: 
What I am looking to do is take a list of blacklisted words, and then search inside of a string of file path names in a csv. Then, I need it to append the new T/F ( or 1/0)  flag to a new column. I'm trying to see if the word "cow" exists inside of a string that looks like allfiles/cowsdesktop/file.docx and then returns a new column that has a True/ False flag.

The code works to spit out the T/F boolean correctly, I just do not know how to print out a final form that has a new column with the T/F flag.

At the end of the day, the csv export needs to look like:

```
path                            / contains_blacklisted_word
allfiles/cowsdesktop/file.docx / TRUE
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 

blacklisted_words = ['dog','cat','fish','cow','chicken'] 

df = pd.read_csv('filepathnames.csv')
blword = '|'.join(blacklisted_words)
df2 = df['Path'].str.lower().str.contains(blword)
print(df2)
df2.to_csv('Finaloutput.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Add a column to already existing df
df['Flag'] = df.Path.str.lower().str.contains(byword)
df.to_csv('Final Output.csv')
```

This will add a column to your original DataFrame without the need to create a new one.

Comment: This worked! I was way overthinking the issue. Thank you!